# I can't rewind or fast forward using react player

Tags: reactjs, video, react-player

I'm trying to put videos with react, when I host the page locally I can rewind and fast forward the video, but when I deployed the project on CI Gitlab, I can't rewind or fast forward using the video bar.

I'm using the react-player library

```
                 <ReactPlayer url={ video }
                    playing="false"
                    controls="true"
                />
```

I don't know if I'm mising some parameters in this tag.

Answer (score 1):

true" and "false" isn't exactly boolean in JS. I think you meant to type true and false without the quotation marks.

Therefore, to solve your problem, your code should be:

```
    <ReactPlayer url={ video }
     playing={false}
     controls={true}/>
```